# Phonegap Orientation Webview Gets Cut

Tags: cordova, webview, uiwebview

Phonegap orientation webview not properly updated. Sometimes rotating the view is fine, sometimes it's not, it cuts the view around 2/3 or 1/3 of its original width. Any one experience the same problem?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: no, and I think it's nothing to do with the framework. I think it's how the webview in phonegap respond to orientation... The width is not correct sometime when orientation changed.